# PostgreSQL Function/Pivot/Join?

Tags: sql, regex, postgresql

I currently have three tables in my database:

tablename: r with 800k records

```
r_key text, name varchar, l_key varchar[]
a1, high street, [r1,r2,r3]
a2, a123, [r1,r2,r3]
a3, orchard street, r4
a4, thomas lane, [r5,r6]
```

tablename: l with 4million records

```
l_key text, 
r1
r2
r3
r4
r5
r6
```

I then have a lookup table that looks like this with 3.6mill records

```
r_key text, l_key text
a1, r1
a1, r2
a1, r3
a2, r1
a2, r2
a2, r3
a3, r4
a4, r5
a4, r6
```

What I am after is a new table that looks like

```
l_key, name, number*
r1, high street, a123
r2, high street, a123
r3, high street, a123
r4, orchard street, NULL
r5, thomas lane, NULL
r6, thomas lane, NULL
```

*The number will come from doing a regex on the name field to find any values which contains numbers

I have tried to use an update statement:

```
UPDATE l SET 
name = (SELECT name 
FROM lookup
INNER JOIN r
ON lookup.r_key = r.r_key
INNER JOIN l
ON lookup.l_key = l_l_key);
```

But the select returns more than one record so I get this error

```
ERROR: more than one row returned by a subquery used as an expression
```

So I then tried to write a function using two cursors to look through the different keys and apply the update but this has been running for hours and I do not think it will work.

I did some research and there is pivot but not sure if it will work in this situation.

Extras: Windows 7 PostgreSQL 9.3

Answer (score 0):

Use the `limit` clause

```
UPDATE l SET 
name = (
    SELECT name 
    FROM
        lookup
        INNER JOIN r ON lookup.r_key = r.r_key
        INNER JOIN l ON lookup.l_key = l_l_key
    limit 1
);
```

http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-select.html#SQL-LIMIT